# Alter X and Y coordinates of graph vertices in iGraph

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

I'm using the `igraph` package to plot a graph that I've created in yEd. This is a graph that should be overlaid on a geographical map, so one of the first things I want to do is alter the vertex coordinates so that they match up to the longitude/latitude they represent. (simple linear transformation)

I tried to use the GraphML format, but iGraph cannot read GraphML files that were created by yEd, so instead, I've saved the graph as a GML file. The structure of the vertex information looks like this:

```
node [
    id  0
    label   ""
    graphics [
        x   2181.0043222386603
        y   1463.6747524664843
        w   5.2609883750396875
        h   5.1510372122625085
        type    "ellipse"
        raisedBorder    0
        fill    "#FFCC00"
        outline "#000000"
    ]
]
```

As you can see, the coordinates are saved within the `graphics` attribute. This is valid GML syntax (at least AFAIK). However, this attribute is not processed correctly by `load_graph` and iGraph doesn't save the coordinates. When I try to extract the vertex attributes, I get this:

```
> vertex_attr(g) %>% glimpse()
# List of 3
#  $ id      : num [1:73] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
#  $ label   : chr [1:73] "" "" "" "" ...
#  $ graphics: chr [1:73] "qÑÜ\020#8" "qÑÜ\020#8" "qÑÜ\020#8" "qÑÜ\020#8" ...
```

How do I load the graph correctly, including x and y coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `igraph` [documentation](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Foreign.html#idm470940295952), it says that one of the limitations of its ability to read `GML` is

> Only node and edge attributes are used, and only if they have a simple
>   type: integer, real or string. So if an attribute is an array or a
>   record, then it is ignored. This is also true if only some values of
>   the attribute are complex.

Which is probably why it's having trouble with the `graphics` attribute. `igraph` should be able to read `graphml` format as well, but likely encounters the same hurdle.

Luckily, if you need a workaround, `GML` is a human-readable format that is relatively easy to parse out. If you just need the `x` and `y` coordinates of the nodes for example, you can do something like this:

```
library(igraph)

g <- read_graph("graph.gml", format="gml") #create graph object

z <- readLines("graph.gml") #create character vector from which to grep out attributes

id <- trimws(gsub("\t\tid\t", " ", z[grep("\t\tid\t", z)])) #retrive node ids 
totid <- length(id) #retrieve number of nodes

#grep for and extract x and y attributes
xcor <- as.numeric(trimws(gsub("\t\t\tx\t", " ", z[grep("\t\t\tx\t", z)])))[1:totid]    
ycor <- as.numeric(trimws(gsub("\t\t\ty\t", " ", z[grep("\t\t\ty\t", z)])))[1:totid]

#edges will also have x and y coordinates, so we need to index by the number of nodes

#add attributes back into graph object
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, "x", value=xcor) 
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, "y", value=ycor)
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. It seems like writing my own parser is going to be the only solution here. If I'm doing that anyway, I'm going to write a parser for GraphML files since they are based on XML structure.